# boto aws pulling down list of instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Folks, I am trying to retrieve not only instance ids of my running machines, but also the aliased names which I've added to them in the aws console.

Is this the proper way to do this? I am not getting back anything interesting....

```
import boto
botoEC2 = boto.connect_ec2('asdf','asdfasdfasdfasdf')
rsv = botoEC2.get_all_instances()
tags = botoEC2.get_all_tags()
print tags
dir (tags)
print tags
print tags.status
print tags.pop
print tags.count
print tags.tagSet
print tags.requestId
print tags.index
print tags.
print tags.requestId
print tags.index
print tags.key_marker

print tags
```

output:
[Tag:ec2tag, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:ec2tag, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name, Tag:Name]

Thanks!

Comment: If you are ever trying to figure out an api, try using IPython, you can tab complete on methods and attributes of objects. Makes this kind of discovery dead simple.

Comment: what you see above are ipython copy/pastes....   so what was i mistyping in the print tags.tab

Comment: Well, get_all_tags returns a list of tag objects, so what you are seeing there are just the normal list methods. You would need to pull an tag object out of that list `tag = tags[0]` and then try autocompleting on that tag object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fetch all the tags

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2('asdf','asdfasdfasdfasdf')

tags = conn.get_all_tags()
for tag in tags:
    print tag.name, tag.value
```

Or you can get the tags associated with just an instance

```
reservation = conn.get_all_instances()[0]
# Yeah I don't know why they have these stupid reservation objects either...
instance = reservation.instances[0]
print instance.tags
# prints a dictionary of the tags {'Name': 'Given name'}
```

**UPDATE Apr 2014:** [Get all instances is going to change it's behaviour in the near future](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_instances). Funnily enough it is going to start returning a list of EC2 instances. You should use `get_all_reservations` now to avoid code breakage during the next major version update.

Comment: What is the point of [0]? Is there only one reservation for all instances, or are there multiple? Not even sure if I am asking this correctly but still would like [0] explained. :)

Comment: I do not question the AWS API. All I know is that `get_all_instances` returns a list of 1 reservation object...

Comment: this will fail if you ever request more than one instance at a time. Use something like `for instance in [res.instances for res in conn.get_all_instances()]:` and loop through them.

Comment: I'm curious, have you ever actually received more than one reservation object from `get_all_instances`? In what situation does this occur? I never have and I believe that it's just a crappily named bit of the API.

Comment: @aychedee A reservation corresponds to a command to start an instance.  Each `run_instances` command will create a corresponding reservation object. It looks like you've been creating all your instances with a single `run_instances` command.